# Python how to do multiprocessing inside of a class?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a code structure that looks like this:

```
Class A:
  def __init__(self):
    processes = []
    for i in range(1000):
      p = Process(target=self.RunProcess, args=i)
      processes.append[p]

    # Start all processes
    [x.start() for x in processes]

  def RunProcess(self, i):
    do something with i...
```

Main script:

```
myA = A()
```

I can't seem to get this to run. I get a runtime error "**An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.**"

How do I get multiple processing working for this? If I use Threading, it works fine but it is as slow as sequential... And I'm also afraid that multiple processing will also be slow because it takes longer for the the process to be created?

Any good tips? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15):

There are a couple of syntax issues that I can see in your code:

- `args` in `Process` expects a tuple, you pass an integer, please change line 5 to:

  `p = Process(target=self.RunProcess, args=(i,))`
- `list.append` is a method and arguments passed to it should be enclosed in `()`, not `[]`, please change line 6 to:

  `processes.append(p)`

As @qarma points out, its not good practice to start the processes in the class constructor. I would structure the code as follows (adapting your example):

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from time import sleep

class A(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do other stuff
        pass

    def do_something(self, i):
        sleep(0.2)
        print('%s * %s = %s' % (i, i, i*i))

    def run(self):
        processes = []

        for i in range(1000):
            p = mp.Process(target=self.do_something, args=(i,))
            processes.append(p)

        [x.start() for x in processes]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A()
    a.run()
```

Comment: Is it possible to limit the number of concurrent processes?

Comment: @akozi, yes. If you use a process pool, then the max number of concurrent processes is going to be limited by the number of pool workers

Comment: @HaleemurAli, in this example: let's say the method `do_something`  returns a value, how do I collect the results?

Comment: Why does this not throw an error, because it couldn't pickle the function? I thought bound functions could not be pickled.

Answer (score 8):

It should simplify things for you to use a `Pool`.  As far as speed, starting up the processes does take time.  However, using a `Pool` as opposed to running `njobs` of `Process` should be as fast as you can get it to run with processes.  The default setting for a `Pool` (as used below) is to use the maximum number of processes available (i.e. the number of CPUs you have), and keep farming out new jobs to a worker as soon as a job completes.  You won't get `njobs`-way parallel, but you'll get as much parallelism that your CPUs can handle without oversubscribing your processors.  I'm using `pathos`, which has a fork of `multiprocessing` because it's a bit more robust than standard `multiprocessing`… and, well, I'm also the author.  But you could probably use `multiprocessing` for this.

```
>>> from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool as Pool
>>> class A(object):
...   def __init__(self, njobs=1000):
...     self.map = Pool().map
...     self.njobs = njobs
...     self.start()
...   def start(self):
...     self.result = self.map(self.RunProcess, range(self.njobs))
...     return self.result
...   def RunProcess(self, i):
...     return i*i
... 
>>> myA = A()
>>> myA.result[:11]
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
>>> myA.njobs = 3
>>> myA.start()  
[0, 1, 4]
```

It's a bit of an odd design to start the `Pool` inside of `__init__`. But if you want to do that, you have to get results from something like `self.result`… and you can use `self.start` for subsequent calls.

Get `pathos` here: https://github.com/uqfoundation

Comment: This is returning 
cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed. Any ideas?

Comment: @boson: what is "this"?  Exactly the code I've posted above?  Because, it shouldn't be using `cPickle` if you have `dill` installed.

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness. I'm running a similar type of program with multiprocessing inside class functions. I just confirmed that I do have dill, so I'm not sure why cPickle is being called.

Comment: @boson: you should create a separate post on SO or a ticket on multiprocess's github.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns. Mike, how come calling a function within the `RunProcess` doesn't work? `def RunProcess(self, i): a = sum_add(i)` ... then `def sum_add(i): return i + 1`.. I get `NameError: global name 'sum_add' is not defined`. sum_add is in the same file as a separate function. How do I call that function? I've tried `global sum_add`. I can call `sum_add` if I move it into the class as `self.sum_add`, but not outside of the class.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns. Seems like once `self.map=Pool().map` is started. The class completely isolates itself.

Comment: @jason: It'd be easier to answer your question in a new SO post, not in the comments of another answer.  For example, it looks like you are using the name `sum_add` before you are declaring it, hence the `NameError`... but it's hard to tell as it's difficult to *see* what your code looks like when it's jammed into comments.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns. Ok Mike, will do. posted it here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54693080/python-pathos-multiprocessing-pool-calling-functions-outside-of-class

Comment: @jason what happened to your question? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

A practical work-around is to break down your class, e.g. like this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, ...):
        pass

    def compute(self):
        procs = [Process(self.run, ...) for ... in ...]
        [p.start() for p in procs]
        [p.join() for p in procs]

    def run(self, ...):
        pass

pool = A(...)
pool.compute()
```

When you fork a process inside `__init__`, the class instance `self` may not be fully initialised anyway, thus it's odd to ask a subprocess to execute `self.run`, although technically, yes, it's possible.

If it's not that, then it sounds like an instance of this issue:

http://bugs.python.org/issue11240