# Python multiprocessing silent failure with class

Tags: python, class, multiprocessing

the following does not work using python 2.7.9, but also does not throw any error or exception. is there a bug, or can multiprocessing not be used in a class?

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def testNonClass(arg):
    print "running %s" % arg
    return arg

def nonClassCallback(result):
    print "Got result %s" % result

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        po = Pool()
        for i in xrange(1, 3):
            po.apply_async(self.det, (i,), callback=self.cb)
        po.close()
        po.join()
        print "done with class"
    po = Pool()
    for i in xrange(1, 3):
        po.apply_async(testNonClass, (i,), callback=nonClassCallback)
    po.close()
    po.join()

    def cb(self, r):
        print "callback with %s" % r

    def det(self, M):
        print "method"
        return M+2


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Foo()
```

running prints this:

```
done with class
running 1
running 2
Got result 1
Got result 2
```

EDIT: THis seems related, but it uses `.map`, while I specifically am needing to use `apply_async` which seems to matter in terms of how multiprocessing works with class instances (e.g. I dont have a picklnig error, like many other questions related to this) - [Python how to do multiprocessing inside of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29009790/python-how-to-do-multiprocessing-inside-of-a-class)

Comment: Why are you creating two different pools? It's probably not a good idea to create the pool in the class block. You can do it in the __init__ or `__name__ == "__main__"` blocks. When you say "does not work" what do you mean, what output do you expect?

Answer (score 1):

Processes don't share state or memory by default, each process is an independent program. You need to either 1) use threading 2) use [specific types capable of sharing state](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) or 3) design your program to avoid shared state and rely on return values instead.

Update

You have two issues in your code, and one is masking the other.

1) You don't do anything with the result of the `apply_async`, I see that you're using callbacks, but you still need to catch the results and handle them. Because you're not doing this, you're not seeing the error caused by the second problem.

2) Methods of an object cannot be passed to other processes... I was really annoyed when I first discovered this, but there is an easy workaround. Try this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def _remote_det(foo, m):
    return foo.det(m)

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
        po = Pool()
        results = []
        for i in xrange(1, 3):
            r = po.apply_async(_remote_det, (self, i,), callback=self.cb)
            results.append(r)

        po.close()
        for r in results:
            r.wait()
            if not r.successful():
                # Raises an error when not successful
                r.get()

        po.join()
        print "done with class"

    def cb(self, r):
        print "callback with %s" % r

    def det(self, M):
        print "method"
        return M+2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Foo()
```

Comment: sorry, state sharing isn't the issue (although it was a bug in my example). The updated questino shows the same problem without usnig any global counters

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it can be used in a class, but you need to protect the call to `Foo` inside of a clause like:

`if name == "__main__":`

so that it only gets called in the main thread. You may also have to alter the `__init__` function of the class so that it accepts a pool as an argument instead of creating a pool.

I just tried this

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

#global counter
#counter = 0

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, po):
        for i in xrange(1, 300):
            po.apply_async(self.det, (i,), callback=self.cb)
        po.close()
        po.join()
        print( "foo" )
        #print counter

    def cb(self, r):
        #global counter
        #print counter, r
        counter += 1


    def det(self, M):
        return M+2


if __name__ == "__main__":
    po = Pool()
    Foo(po)
```

and I think I know what the problem is now. Python isn't multi-threaded; global interpreter lock prevents that. Python is using multiple processes, instead, so the sub-processes in the Pool don't have access to the standard output of the main process.

The subprocesses also are unable to modify the variable `counter` because it exists in a different process (I tried running with the `counter` lines commented out and uncommented). Now, I do recall seeing cases where global state variables get altered by processes in the pool, so I don't know all of the minutiae. I do know that it is, in general, a bad idea to have global state variables like that, if for no other reason than they can lead to race conditions and/or wasted time with locks and waiting for access to the global variable.

Comment: Thanks. I removed the counter and added an example proving that the output from subprocesses is not causing the failure. Problem still happens-  it's using class methods that is causing this failure